# Raspberry pi leds does not blink and the ic gets hot

Tags: board-leds

I bought my raspberry pi 3 model B 4 months back. It was working perfectly but one day, when I was working on pi, all of a sudden, it stopped working. After that day, when I am trying to power it up again, none of the red and green leds are blinking even for a second. Also, the central ic starts getting hot immediately. Has anyone faced a similar problem and came up with a solution to it? Also, since it's been just 4 months that I bought pi from amazon.in, will I be able to replace the product as it is still in the 1 year warranty period? Any suggestions are welcomed.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried a different power cable ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried three different power cables to power up the pi but nothing worked.

Comment: As you mentioned Warranty with Amazon, it would probably be easier to just return it. If you have any other way of checking to see if you're data is still accessible on the memory card then go that way. But try remember what could have caused the Pi to brick, and then ensure you dont replicate it on a new one etc.

Comment: If your Pi is overheating you could try one of [these](http://www.dx.com/p/ultimate-dual-cooling-fan-kit-module-for-raspberry-pi-3b-2b-no-pi-477341?tc=USD&ta=US&gclid=CjwKCAiAvf3RBRBBEiwAH5XYqEMcnycDUSgCHW9RWxe7HpwPm9jaP36FBZIvXz7S5TAW-od-lpUZ4RoCOIUQAvD_BwE) otherwise return for warranty like BantuTech said

Answer (score 1):

Trying another power cable, or adding a fan makes no sense when there is **no** response from the LED's. You must have a serious electrical problem and in that case I would recommend you to send your Pi back to the supplier.

Answer (score 1):

The IC getting hot is a usual sing of electrical damage. It's likely that you inadvertently connected some pins/pads that shouldn't be connected while working on your Pi and that killed it. Make sure you always power down the device when you connect/disconnect something except USB which explicitly supports hot-plugging.

Normally, you are not entitled to a free repair/replacement if you damaged the product yourself. However, unless there are visible traces of damage (typically that includes traces of water and physically broken parts), the manufacturer may not be able to prove that the damage was inflicted by you (and perhaps it wasn't), so they are likely to agree to replace it under warranty.

I'm not familiar with policies of amazon.in, but AFAIK Amazon handles returns during a 30-day period, after which you'll have to follow the return procedure defined by the seller. Such policies are available on the seller's page on Amazon.

Comment: It's a long shot but it's also worth suggesting that you at least _try_ to "ground" yourself before working on ESD sensitive parts by touching a cold water tap or bare radiator pipe first, unless you have anti-static mats and straps to hand.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no response from the LEDs, the Pi is very likely fried. Returning it to your supplier for an exchange would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

> Hmmm, there is no try.

I would put money on the fact that you were doing some ***wiring*** to the Pi and got something wrong!

Next time, double check your wiring. Then, check it again.

Don't do wiring when the Pi has power connected, even if shut-down!

I've been there and done that... twice (but shhhhh, don't tell anyone!)

> I was working on pi, all of a sudden, it stopped working.