# Abnormal overheating Rpi3

Tags: pi-3

My raspberry pi gives me heat warning after 5 minutes it is turned on. I tried heat sink on my Pi and the only difference it made that it gave me warning after 10 to 15 mins rather giving it the moment it was turned on. Now i used fan along with heat sink. It dropped the temperature to 56 degree celsius. This is a quite abnornal behaviour. I am not running ANY program on pi and CPU usage is always 1 to 7 percent.

Comment: Does it have good ventilation?

Comment: Yes it has. It has the same environment and peripherals and everything before it was overheating. I dont know why but it has started overheating to abnornal level from few days back.

Comment: What are you running on it? I used to have a RPi3 that I would run mining software on and I always ran a fan with it. With a fan the cpu temp hovered at around 50 degrees celcius

Answer (score 2):

This is likely caused by a faulty (over-voltage) power supply, static damage, over-loading the 3V3 rail, over-loading a GPIO or some other [wiring mistake](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/raspberry-pi-leds-does-not-blink-and-the-ic-gets-hot/89636#89636).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from raspberry pi, I have seen in Lab that when an IC starts abnormal overheating, It means its near death. I wish, it may not happen to Your Pi, dear Muhammad Naufil, but ... and (base on what You have said), I am concluding (based on my experience), that You should have an other Pi.